# Which crown features on the Japanese Order of the Precious Crown?

Tags: japan, imperial-japan

The [Order of the Precious Crown](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Precious_Crown#:~:text=The%20Order%20of%20the%20Precious,and%20eighth%20classes%20were%20added.) features a crown on its [badge](http://www.imperialjapanmedalsandbadges.com/sacredcrown.html). I cannot determine which crown this is.

The order was founded in 1888 by [Emperor Meiji](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Meiji), who I cannot find depicted wearing or with any such crown.

Indeed, the crown looks similar to that worn by [Emperor Kammu](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Emperor_Kammu_large.jpg#mw-jump-to-license) (735-806), but I cannot find any confirmation of which exact crown it depicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in the [Japanese Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AE%9D%E5%86%A0%E7%AB%A0#%E6%84%8F%E5%8C%A0) of the article *Order of the Precious Crown*,

> 章の意匠は、古代の女帝の冠（宝冠）の形状...

These are crowns worn by Japanese *Empresses* rather than Emperors. The crown used in the coronation of [Empress *Go-Sakuramachi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empress_Go-Sakuramachi) shows almost exactly the shape of the crown in the badge.

[image]

Comment: @Johan88 a picture of the actual crown used in her coronation should be more convincing...edited.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! You have such an amazing talent for research!!